# Move WordPress from /blog folder to root but leave post at /blog

Tags: blog

I am working on a WordPress blog for a client.  Currently they have around 3,000 posts.

The WordPress is installed at `/blog/`

I need to move the WordPress install to the Root directory but still have the Blog posts show up at `/blog/` so after I move the blog, all the Post URLs will remain the same.

I have to do this regardless of how I do it this has to be the outcome.  I'm hoping for an easier method though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an empty page with the slug `blog`.
2. Go to *Settings/Reading* and set that page as *Posts page*.
3. Go to *Settings/Permalinks* and set the URL pattern to `/blog/%postname%/`.

That should do it.